# How can I handle this PEP8 warning?

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8, pep

I have a two-line code like this:

```
if validated_data.get('is_shipped') == False:  # 管理员取消了发货，则把物流信息删掉
    validated_data.update(logistics_company=None, logistics_tracking_no=None)
```

I am using `Pycharm` and the PEP8 check is on. So there is an underline below `validated_data.get('is_shipped') == False` which shows me ``` Expression can be simplified. Replace boolean expression with ``not validated_data.get('is_shipped')`` ``` . But, the truth is, I only want to run code in `if` statement when `is_shipped` is explicitly passed as `False`, and not when `is_shipped` is `None`. So, how can I handle this PEP8 check warning?

Comment: 在这里，把 == 替换成 is 就好，但友情提示，部分情况下 PEP8 的警告可以忽略，尤其是在涉及运算符重载的时候，因为 is 无法被重载。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit the solution in your question: use the explicit `is` operator:

```
if validated_data.get('is_shipped') is False:
```

This makes your condition an explicit identity, rather than the "truthy" boolean evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Here `x == False` is equivalent to `not x`, and I don't know why do you want to only use `x == False` and PEP8 suggests that:

```
if not validated_data.get('is_shipped'):  # 管理员取消了发货，则把物流信息删掉
    validated_data.update(logistics_company=None, logistics_tracking_no=None)
```

Comment: `is_shipped` maybe `None` or `False`, I only want to handle when `is_shipped` is False.